# handle Control + enter in a multiline textbox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

I am trying to handle Ctrl+Enter keydown event in my winapp project.

```
  private void txtAnswer_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter && e.KeyCode==Keys.Control)
        {
            //Some statements.
        }
    }
```

But, it's not working. Any help?

Comment: Look at your condition - how can `e.KeyCode` simultaneously be `Keys.Enter` and `Keys.Control` when those are different values?

Comment: I've done something similar ... I'll have a look and report back ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be [`Control.ModifierKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys(v=vs.110).aspx) as below: <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>

```
private void txtAnswer_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Ok KeyDown");
    }
}
```

EDIT: To prevent the newline:

```
private bool keydowncalled = false;
private void txtAnswer_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    keydowncalled = false;

    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Enter))
    {
        keydowncalled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Ok KeyDown");
    }
}

private void txtAnswer_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (keydowncalled == true)
    {
        // Stop the newline from being entered into the control.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol ...by the time I've found it, you wrote it ...good ... :)

Comment: @Vishal Suthar , It's working, but still a new line is created. How to prevent a new line?

Comment: @VishalSuthar Thanks. Finally its working as expected.

Comment: There's a simpler way than that.  You can suppress the `KeyPress` event in the `KeyDown` event handler so not need to handle both events.  See the edit in my answer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney But this will not work if OP also want the messagebox for the keys pressed.

Comment: @VishalSuthar, of course it will.  You simply add an `if` statement.  You can either use an `if` statement to test `e.KeyData` first and then make the assignment and show the message only if `true` or you could add an `if` statement to test `e.SuppressKeyPress` afterwards.  Both would work.  That said, I think it's a moot point anyway because surely that message was simply a tool to determine whether the code was catching the key combination or not, where a breakpoint should have been used instead.  I doubt that it would be included in the production code.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to detect a key and modifiers then you test `e.KeyData`, not `e.KeyCode`.  In this case:

```
if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Enter))
```

Note that that is a bitwise OR of the `Control` modifier key and the `Enter` key.

EDIT:

If the point is to prevent a line break being added on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> then this is what you should do:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Enter));
}
```